# Using an ACF text field to display metatag on specific pages. Can't get the acf field to return correctly in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am in the process of implementing ios smart banners on our site, however we only want it to display on selected pages. I have set up an ACF text field, where I have the page IDs as a comma separated string ( eg: 1234, 1235, 1236, 1237 ).

In the functions.php file I have created the following function to add the metatag to the correct pages:

```
function enable_app_banner()
{
    $enabledpages = the_field('allowed_pages', 'options');
    
    if (is_page([$enabledpages])) {
        echo '<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=12345678">';
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'enable_app_banner');
```

However this is not getting me the result I require, annoyingly it works when hardcoding in the values into the array as such;

```
if (is_page([1234, 1235, 1236])) {
        echo '<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=12345678">';
    }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"annoyingly it works when hardcoding in the values"_ - that's because `[1, 2, 3]` and `["1, 2, 3"]` are of course totally different things. Learn to differentiate between _code_, and _data_! Use `explode` on your comma-separated string value, to get an actual array.

Comment: Thank you buddy! I really appreciate the assistance. I have learnt something new today and will do a bit more reading up on the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you setup an ACF text field which gives you *a comma separated string ( eg: 1234, 1235, 1236, 1237 ).* but `is_page()` method accepts array of IDs.

You have to convert the string into array first. Use `explode()` method to do so:

```
function enable_app_banner() {
  $enabledpages = the_field('allowed_pages', 'options');
  // Using explode method to convert comma separated string into an array.
  $enabledPagesArray = explode(', ', $enabledpages);

  if (is_page($enabledPagesArray)) {
    echo '<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=12345678">';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, apologies for my lack of knowledge around this area, I have learnt something new and I really appreciate your assistance guys. Its now working perfectly

Comment: @xDE4DSH0Tx Great! Keep learning. If it helps please mark the answer as accepted and close this ticket